# Java OSGI. Maven vs Eclipse+Ant - best practice

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I have programmed quite a bit of java, and are familiar with maven and eclipse,
but I haven't made an OSGi before.

Our scenario is this:

- Create an OSGi bundle, intended to being dropped in as a plugin to an already existing and proprietary java webapp, in tomcat.
- The code of the OSGi bundle will have to rely on specific libraries already present in the exisitng webapp, thus, we must specify the dependencies in the manifest file, and not actually link the libraries. (but we still need the jars present during compile)
- Also, since the libraries are propriatry, they do not exist in the maven repositories.

**The dilemma:**
I got a modular maven build for all my applications, but using maven for creating this OSGi bundle seems a bit tedious.

- I've found an OSGi-bundle plugin for maven, but it seems a bit tricky to setup, in order to get everything right.
- Since we're depending on a lot of propritary jars, we need to specify each jar in the pom, and require a mvn install of those libraries beforehand, for every developer working on it(it's not just me). Either that, or setup our own internal maven repo for this purpose. And if we recieve a new product update to our propritary software, all the jar versions are likely to change.

So to sum up, it seems to me that using maven for this task, is adding a lot of overhead and complexity, without really gaining much, as manually checking of dependencies will be required anyway.

I'm tempted to dump every jar we need into our version control repo, create an eclipse project for this(Eclipse support OSGi rather well), and point the classpath to the needed jars(for compiling purposes only..they're not actually bundled with the jar obviously).
Then have eclipse generate an ant buildscript for it in the end.

This will be fast and rather painless. Anyone got any suggestion? Maven way? eclipse way? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(note: I'm not qualified to answer that as I'm not very good with maven+osgi)

First of all, where does the OSGi framework lie w.r.t your web app? Is the app itself starting  the framework or does the framework start the app? e.g.

- tomcat > webapp+libs > osgi
- tomcat > osgi > webapp+libs

The current architecture will limit your possible avenues.

Have you considered mavenizing the existing third-party libraries and having an internal maven repo? While you're at it you could add OSGi metadata to them. This will allow you to build your bundles as stand-alone bundles *without* linking in each and every library. If you use package imports (recommended) and not bundle imports, you can avoid installing the OSGi-fied 3rd party jars in the OSGi framework; instead you modify the framework startup and specify that all the packages in the 3rd-party jars are povided by the original class loader.

Comment: I agree wuth Tassos: 

When working with Maven it is recommended to use a Maven Repository Manager such as Nexus and configure your settings file as described here:

http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html

In your situation this has the additional benefit that you could use the Maven Repository Manager to host any private artifacts.